# Map function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

Im getting undefined on my app = TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined and my console.log(cartoons) and i dont know what the issue is. im passing props the right way or im wrong? please help :(

this is my Cardlist.js file

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import Card from '../components/Card';


const Cardlist = ({ cartoons }) => {
   console.log(cartoons);
    return (
        <Fragment> 
            {
                cartoons.map((user, i) => {
                    return (
                        <Card 
                            key={i}
                            id={cartoons[i].id} 
                            name={cartoons[i].name}
                            email={cartoons[i].email}
                        />
                    ); 
                })
            }
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default Cardlist;
```

this is also my cartoons.js file

```
export const cartoons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    email: 'Sincere@april.biz'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ervin Howell',
    username: 'Antonette',
    email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Clementine Bauch',
    username: 'Samantha',
    email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net'
  },
];
```

Comment: May you make sure your shared code is a [mcve]? How are you using `Cardlist` and `cartoons`?

Comment: Are you passing your cartoons as a prop? `<Cardlist cartoons={cartoons} />`

Comment: You must call `Cardlist` function with a parameter that has `cartoons` property. E.g. `Cardlist({cartoons : []});`

Comment: Try this `{ cartoons && cartoons.map((user, i) => { ... } }`

Answer (score 0):

map function requires data of type array.cartoons variable seems to be empty or not an array data type assign empty array if its value is null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with container pattern for best practice:

cartoonDb.js

```
// cartoonDb.js
export const cartoons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    email: 'Sincere@april.biz'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ervin Howell',
    username: 'Antonette',
    email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Clementine Bauch',
    username: 'Samantha',
    email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net'
  },
];
```

CardListContainer.js

```
// CardListContainer.js

import React from './CardList';
import CardList from './CardList';
import {cartoons} from './cartoonDb';

export default class CardListContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <CardList cartoons={cartoons} />
  }
}
```

CardList.js

```
// CardList.js
import React from './CardList';

export default const CardList = ({ cartoons }) => (
 <div className="cardList">
    {cartoons.map(cartoon => (
       <Card 
         key={cartoon.id}
         name={cartoon.name}
         email={cartoon.email}
       />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code, `cartoons[0]` is undefined.

When using map function, array index starts from 0.

You can use `cartoons[i+1]` or `user.id`.

Hope this helps!

```
cartoons.map((user, i) => {
                    return (
                        <Card 
                            key={i+1}
                            id={user.id}  
                            name={user.name} 
                            email={user.email} 
                        />
                    ); 
                })
```

Comment: Your code makes some sense (at least except the commented out bits). You description makes none. The `ID` might start from 1, but the index (`i`) starts at zero.